# How to collect submitted values of a List<T> in JSF?

Tags: jsf, foreach, dynamic-forms, uirepeat

I have a bean with a `List<T>`:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;
    private String value;

    @Inject
    private ItemService itemService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = itemService.list();
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Submitted value: " + value);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to edit the `value` property of every item:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

With this code the `value` doesn't contain all the submitted values, only the latest submitted value. I also tried `<c:forEach>` and `<h:dataTable>`, but it didn't made any difference.

What should I do for collecting all the submitted values?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused because you're basically collecting all submitted values into **one and same** bean property. You need to move the `value` property into the bean behind `var="item"`.

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" /> <!-- instead of #{bean.value} -->
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

In the bean action method, simply iterate over `items` in order to get all submitted values via `item.getValue()`.

```
public void submit() {
    for (Item item : items) {
        System.out.println("Submitted value: " + item.getValue());
    }
}
```